# Using second USB keyboard directly from C without OS

Tags: 20.04, usb, keyboard, usbhid

I have two USB keyboards.

At the moment, the input from both keyboards is merged together.

How can I stop the second keyboard from being captured by the OS and use it in my own C program?

(I'm assuming some form of udev configuration, but I'm not sure where to start.)

How would I use a non-OS keyboard from within C?  (I'm fine with raw scan codes, or even HID messages at worst.)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this can be done easily in Python: https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#getting-exclusive-access-to-a-device

Therefore it should just be a matter of ioctls on /dev/input/eventN in C.